# Obtaining $h_i$ by evaluating $f(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(-h_i s)h_i$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, laplace-transform, numerical-optimization, integral-transforms

Suppose I'm able to obtain values of $f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(m)$ with $f$ defined as follows:
$$f(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(-h_i s)h_i$$

Is there a numerical procedure to obtain $h_1,\ldots,h_n$? We know that $h_{i}>h_{i+1}$ and that $h_i>0$. In practice $n>10^6$ and $f(0)$ can be bounded independently of $n$ (hence $h_i$ decay to 0), so $\int_1^\infty$ is a good approximation of $\sum_{i=1}^n$.

**background**: $f(0),f(1),\ldots$ are multiples of loss observed while doing gradient descent on quadratic with eigenvalues $h_i$. Solving this problem would let you get Hessian spectrum from sequence of loss values. Some extra regularity assumption may need to be added to make this useful. (mathematica.SE [crosspost](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250833/obtain-h-1-h-2-ldots-from-f0-f1-f2-ldots-with-fs-sum-i) with numeric examples).

Comment: If $m\ge n$, brute force numerics should work.  If $m\lt n$, questionable.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici regression will be numerically unstable for large $h_i$ and for closely spaced pairs of $(h_i,h_{i+1})$. I think some kind of additional weighting, for example maximum-entropy biasing or related, may help to improve the confidence in the results.

Comment: Maybe an adaptation of [Prony's method](https://na.math.uni-goettingen.de/pdf/Pe13.pdf)?